# How to properly use Java Executor?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, java.util.concurrent, threadpoolexecutor

I've used Java Executors in my multi-threading apps, but I can't seem to figure out when is the best to use each of the following ways:

1.

```
ExecutorService executor=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);
executor.execute(new A_Runner(... some parameter ...));
executor.shutdown();
while (!executor.isTerminated()) { Thread.sleep(100); }
```

2.

```
int Page_Count=200;
ExecutorService executor=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);
doneSignal=new CountDownLatch(Page_Count);
for (int i=0;i<Page_Count;i++) executor.execute(new A_Runner(doneSignal, ... some parameter ...));
doneSignal.await();
executor.shutdown();
while (!executor.isTerminated()) { Thread.sleep(100); }
```

3.

```
int Executor_Count=30;
ThreadPoolExecutor executor=new ThreadPoolExecutor(Executor_Count,Executor_Count*2,1,TimeUnit.SECONDS,new LinkedBlockingQueue());
List<Future<String>> futures=new ArrayList<>(3330);

for (int i=0;i<50;i++) futures.add(executor.submit(new A_Runner(... some parameter ...));
executor.shutdown();
while (!executor.isTerminated()) { executor.awaitTermination(1,TimeUnit.SECONDS); }
for (Future<String> future : futures)
{
    String f=future.get();
    // ...
}
```

Specifically, in [2] what if I skip the doneSignal, then it'll be like [1], so what's the use for the doneSignal?

Also, in [3], what if I add a doneSignal? Or is it possible?

What I'd like to know is : are these approaches interchangeable, or is there a certain situation that I'm supposed to use a specific type above?

Comment: For those who are still confused, I solved my problem after reading this particular web post.
This is the link : <http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html> Sorry for I know this answer is too late.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

   `ExecutorService executor=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);`

   It is simple and easy to use. It hides low level details of `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

   Prefer this one when number of `Callable/Runnable` tasks are small in number and piling of tasks in unbounded queue does not increase  memory & degrade the performance of the system. If you have `CPU/Memory` constraints,  use `ThreadPoolExecutor` with capacity constraints & `RejectedExecutionHandler` to handle rejection of tasks.
2. [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)

   You have initialized `CountDownLatch` with a given count. This count is decremented by calls to the `countDown()` method. I am assuming that you are calling decrement in your Runnable task later. Threads waiting for this count to reach zero can call one of the `await()` methods. Calling `await()` blocks the thread until the count reaches zero. *This class enables a java thread to wait until other set of threads completes their tasks.*

   *Use cases:*

   1. Achieving Maximum Parallelism: Sometimes we want to start a number of threads at the same time to achieve maximum parallelism
   2. Wait N threads to completes before start execution
   3. Deadlock detection.

      Have a look at this [article](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/07/18/when-to-use-countdownlatch-java-concurrency-example-tutorial/) by Lokesh Gupta for more details.
3. [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) : It provides more control to finetune various thread pool parameters. If your application is constrained by number of active `Runnable/Callable` tasks, you should  use bounded queue by setting the max capacity. Once the queue reaches maximum capacity, you can define RejectionHandler. Java provides four types of `RejectedExecutionHandler` [policies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).

   1. In the default `ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy`, the handler throws a runtime RejectedExecutionException upon rejection.
   2. In `ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy`, the thread that invokes execute itself runs the task. This provides a simple feedback control mechanism that will slow down the rate that new tasks are submitted.
   3. In `ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy`, a task that cannot be executed is simply dropped.
   4. In `ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardOldestPolicy`, if the executor is not shut down, the task at the head of the work queue is dropped, and then execution is retried (which can fail again, causing this to be repeated.)

      If you want to simulate `CountDownLatch` behaviour, you can use `invokeAll()` method.
4. One more mechanism you did not quote is [ForkJoinPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html)

   The `ForkJoinPool` was added to Java in Java 7. The `ForkJoinPool` is similar to 
   the Java `ExecutorService` but with one difference. The `ForkJoinPool` makes it 
   easy for tasks to split their work up into smaller tasks which are then 
   submitted to the `ForkJoinPool` too. Task stealing happens in `ForkJoinPool`   when free worker threads steal tasks from busy worker thread queue.

   Java 8 has introduced one more API in [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to create work stealing pool. You don't have to create `RecursiveTask` and `RecursiveAction` but still can use `ForkJoinPool`.

   ```
     public static ExecutorService newWorkStealingPool()
   ```

   > Creates a work-stealing thread pool using all available processors as its target parallelism level.

   By default, it will take number of CPU cores as parameter.

All these four mechanism are complimentary to each other. Depending on level of granularity you want to control, you have to chose right ones.