# New thread multiple times

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want to run a thread when I press a button

```
public void ButtonClick(){

    Thread thread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            Log.i("Test", "I'm in thread");
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}
```

My question is : I want to click several times on this button. Are several thread still existing after the message "I'm in thread" is printed? Or each time the run function is finished, the thread is destroyed?

In case I create several threads which are running at the same time, how can I close them in a clean way?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you should use ExecutorService instead of creating new threads manually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Are several thread still existing after the message "I'm in thread" is
>   printed?

No. Each of them will be destroyed automatically.

> In case I create several threads which are running at the same time,
>   how can I close them in a clean way?

No need to stop threads, they will be destroyed automatically once they finish their task(execution of *run*).

To handle the concurrency and safety you should look in to [`java.util.concurrent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) which is utility framework for handling concurrency in java.

Comment: And java does not provide a way to stop another thread, since it is **not safe**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're the only one to answer directly my question instead of giving me another solution!

Answer (score 2):

> Are several thread still existing after the message "I'm in thread" is printed? Or each time the run function is finished, the thread is destroyed?

In your case, you are creating many threads since a Thread is created for every button click.

The life span of Thread is over after completion of last statement in `run()` method. After execution of `run()` method, the thread will enter into `TERMINATED` [State](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html) and it can't be re-run.

Better solution is not creating a new Thread for every button click. If you need more Threads in your application, go for a pool of Threads.

Java provides [Executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) framework for this purpose. It manages Thread life cycle in better way.

Use one of APIs, which will return `ExecutorService` from [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)

e.g. `newFixedThreadPool(4)`

Have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33596079/how-to-properly-use-java-executor/33596230#33596230) and this [article](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html)  for more options.

> In case I create several threads which are running at the same time, how can I close them in a clean way?

You can shutdown the `ExecutorService` as quoted in below SE post:

[How to properly shutdown java ExecutorService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36644043/how-to-properly-shutdown-java-executorservice/36644320#36644320)

Since you are using Android, you have one more good alternative for multithreading : [HandlerThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) and [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Refer to below post for more details:

[Android: Toast in a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134683/android-toast-in-a-thread/45922317#45922317)

Comment: This does not answer the question and is comment at best.

Comment: If you're going to add that the thread "will be destroyed," then you might mention the reason why.  Termination _allows_ the thread to be destroyed, but it does not _cause_ the thread to be destroyed.  A `Thread` object is destroyed for the same reason any other object is destroyed:  The GC reclaims it when there are no live references.  The only thing special about a `Thread` object is that as long a the thread is running, there will be a live reference from within the JVM implementation code.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Removed confusing words.

Answer (score 0):

Creating Thread everytime is a bad idea use Thread Pool.

Answer (score 0):

create a class implementing Runnable instead of Anonymous thread ... pass runnable object creating as many threads as you likeSince creating Anonymous Runnable object creates only one object thus limiting you to achieve your requirements. Check the thread status before creating another or create a thread group (depreciated) or a thread pool using concurrency you use callable instead of runnable and pass it to thread pool of definite size or you could convert runnable to callable and then pass it to the pool as many times as you like

```
class Thop implements Runnable
 {
         public void run()
        {
                  // operation
         }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!