# Spring TaskExecutor Implementation Queue Priorization

Tags: java, spring, queue, executor

The application I am working on receives notifications from external systems, which I want to process.

Till now I have the following implementation:

```
    public class AsynchronousServiceImpl implements AsynchronousService {

    private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    @Override
    public void executeAsynchronously(Runnable task) {
        taskExecutor.execute(task);
    }

    @Required
    public void setTaskExecutor(TaskExecutor taskExecutor) {
        this.taskExecutor = taskExecutor;
    }
}
```

spring configuration (I only need 1 thread since I don't want to execute the notifications in parallel due some legacy issues which are hard to change)

```
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="1"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="1"/>
    <property name="WaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Here I execute then the code:

```
 asynchronousService.executeAsynchronously(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         someMethod.processNotification(notification)
      }
   });
```

This Notification object which I have contains a timestamp field.
I want to prioritize the notifications in the queue by this field (I think Spring uses as default an unbounded queue which is fine more me, since I need an unbounded queue)

Can I integrate this somehow in my spring application without implementing it manually from scratch? So I want to sort the taskss (runnable-objects) in the queue based on the timestamp field on the notification object.(It is that object that I am passing to the "processNotification" method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` is backed by `BlockingQueue`:

```
protected BlockingQueue<Runnable> createQueue(int queueCapacity) {
    if (queueCapacity > 0) {
        return new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(queueCapacity);
    }
    else {
        return new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>();
    }
}
```

If you want to order your task, you need to override this function to allow priority ordering:

```
public class YourPool extends ThreadPoolTaskExecutor {
    @Override
    protected BlockingQueue<Runnable> createQueue(int queueCapacity) {
        return new PriorityBlockingQueue<>(queueCapacity);
    }
}
```

Your submitted task must be comparable:

```
public class YourTask implements Runnable, Comparable<YourTask> {
    private Notification notification;

    public YourTask(Notification notification) {
        this.notification = notification;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        someMethod.processNotification(notification)
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(B other) {
        // Here you implement the priority
        return notification.getTimestamp().compareTo(other.notification.getTimestamp());
    }
}
```

Then submit your task:

```
asynchronousService.executeAsynchronously(new YourTask(notificationX));
```

Comment: Thx very much for your answer. I've one question though. In the end, I need to use the my new Pool (YourPool). But i need to override the method (createQueue) of my bean (taskExecutor) in order to reuse it?

Comment: Yes. You must override method createQueue to use custom queue like my sample code. Your bean must be of type "yourPool"

Comment: Yeah I did that - I'm just wondering if the taskExecutor - bean defined in my xml-file becomes obsolete?

Comment: If you still use xml to configure your bean then you must provide `YourPool` in `class=` attribute

Comment: And futhermore, in the class: "YourTask"  I call the method "someMethod" which is defined in another Service. But I cannot autowire (this service in the YourTask class) an object in Spring created with new. My whole concern is who to integrate this in a Spring-MVC Application

Comment: Then create another field `someMethod`  in `YourTask` and pass the actuall service when construct the task

Comment: Yeah I actually did that, I was just not sure if there is a better way. Thanks very much for your help

Comment: I know this does not belong here, but do you know any tricks or some articles which explain how one can unit test this stuff?

Comment: Since I want to use an unbounded queue, I need to pass Integer.MAX_VALUE as the queueCapacity in the xml configuration, like this: 
<property name="queueCapacity" value="#{T(java.lang.Integer).MAX_VALUE}"/> - right?

Comment: However, if you do this, like I did in my previous comment, then of course you would get an OutOfMemoryError -Exception

Comment: You need to find a way to bound your queue, I'll come to you tonight. Now I am at work

Comment: But I need an unbounded queue, since I cannot afford to process all tasks. It is too risky to loose 1 task. I don't understand why I cannot use it, since the spring default task-executor also uses an unbounded queu

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172082/discussion-between-mnh-quyt-nguyn-and-norbert94).

Comment: Hi, go to the chat room