# Multiple threads handler vs ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: android, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I have some managers that execute different tasks and I need that this tasks are executed in background to keep the main Thread free. So, I'm using 3 threads and communicating them with handlers (with a main manager).
I've read about the ThreadPoolExecutor and I was thinking about the benefits of this class against my actual implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ThreadPoolExecutor` is an [`ExecutorService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) that execute each task on a thread auto managed by him.[`ExecutorService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) is a high level API and more easy to managed.

In addition, there are several types of `ExecutorService` that you can invoke through [`Executors`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) factory.

You can view more about `Executor` on this thread: [How to properly use Java Executor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33596079/how-to-properly-use-java-executor/33596230#33596230)